# Converting a string to a Dictionary of type Dictionary<string, List<string>>() using C#

Tags: c#, json, dictionary

I have a string `"{yhxj7027DO=[3], lzpd7453EH=[2, 3]}"`. I would like to convert it to a Dictionary of type `new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()`. I tried the following

```
string = "{yhxj7027DO=[value1], lzpd7453EH=[value2, value3]}"
var strArr = input.Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "").Split("],", StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries);
            for (int i = 0; i < strArr.Length - 1; i++) strArr[i] += "]";
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("{");
            foreach (var item in strArr)
            {
                var arr = item.Split("=");
                sb.Append("\"" + arr[0] + "\"" + ":" + arr[1] + ",");
            }

            sb.Append("}");
            var json = sb.ToString().Replace(",}", "}");

            Dictionary<string, string[]> result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string[]>>(json);
```

I have the following error: `Unexpected character encountered while parsing number: :. Path 'lzpd7453EH[0]', line 1, position 36.`  What could be the problem?

Comment: You cant write the symbol `"` in a string without escaping it first. All `"` between the beginning of the string and the end should be replaced with `\"` to escape it.

Comment: if you are using the latest dotnet version, you should be able to enclose the string with tree quotes `"""{yhxj7027DO=["value1"]..."""` so no escaping is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is syntax in how you are defining the input string. First, you aren't naming the variable `input`, which seems to be what the rest of your code expects. Second, your `value1`, `value2`, and `value3` aren't variable. (EDIT: Your edit to your question removed the hint that `value1`, etc. should be interpolated, but I've left the below information in case you do want to interpolate those values.)

You can use string interpolation:

```
string input = $"{{yhxj7027DO=[{value1}], lzpd7453EH=[{value2}, {value3}]}}";
```

But notice you have to escape the `{` and `}` characters by doubling them up. You could use concatenation as well:

```
string input = "{yhxj7027DO=[" + value1 + "], lzpd7453EH=["+ value2 + ", " + value3 + "]}";
```

If you need to include double quotes in the string literal than you can use a "[raw string literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-11.0/raw-string-literal)" or just escape the quotes with a `\` character.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you don't mind if I changed it up a bit. This achieves what you want I believe. I build in some safeguards incase string doesn't contain what you expect.

```
string json = "{yhxj7027DO=[value1], lzpd7453EH=[value2, value3]}";
json = json.StartsWith("{") ? json.Substring(1) : json;
json = json.EndsWith("}") ? json.Substring(0, json.Length - 2) : json;
Dictionary<string, string[]> result = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
foreach (var objects in json.Split("],"))
{
    var jsonSplitted = objects.Split("=");
    if (jsonSplitted?.Length >= 2)
    {
        var property = jsonSplitted[0]?.Trim();
        var value = jsonSplitted[1]?.Substring(1);
        var values = value?.Split(", ");
        if (property != null && values != null)
        {
            result.Add(property, values);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions for that. The following works for your example input but requires polishing.

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"((?<key>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)=)\[((?<value>\w+)[^\w\]]*)+\]");
    string input = "{yhxj7027DO=[value1], lzpd7453EH=[value2, value3]}";
    
    var matches = re.Matches(input);

    var results = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
    
    foreach(Match match in matches)
    {
        var values = match.Groups["value"].Captures.Select(x => x.Value);
        results.Add(match.Groups["key"].Value, new List<string>(values));
    }

    // Print results
    foreach(var pair in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{pair.Key}: {string.Join(", ", pair.Value)}");  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `RegEx` to split and then build up the `IDictionary<string, List<string>>`.

```cs
// The regex pattern to use for parsing the input string
string pattern = @"(([\w]+)=\[[0-9,]+\])";

// Your input string copied from your question
string input = @"{yhxj7027DO=[3],lzpd7453EH=[2,3]}";
RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;
       
var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
{
    // The groups should match the parts of the input string 
    var index = m.Value.IndexOf("=");
    var first = m.Value.Substring(0, index);

    // Remove the leading and ending "[" and "]"
    var rest = m.Value.Substring(index + 1).Replace("[", "").Replace("]","");
    
    // Fill up the dictionarys values with the strings
    dict[first]= rest.Split(",").Select(s => $"{s}").ToList();
}
```

Here is a working example in [dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/T8px3v)